# SQL C# Check if record exists, if exists delete

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Using stored procedures to try to check if a record exists or not, if it does it should do so by deleting and giving the appropriate message, if not send another message. here is my C# code.

```
protected void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int deletedCustomers;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCustID.Text))
    {
        lblError.Text = "Please enter a valid Customer ID";
        return;
    }
    else
    {
       dynamic procedure = "dbo.deleteCustomer";

       using (command = new SqlCommand(procedure, conn))
       {
           command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
           command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustID", txtCustID.Text);
       }

       try
       {
           conn.Open();
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();
           deletedCustomers = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

           if (deletedCustomers > 0) {
               lblError.Text = "Deleted!";   
           }
           else
           {
               lblError.Text = "Customer ID does not exist";
           }

           conn.Close();              
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           lblError.Text = "Error: " + ex.Message;
           conn.Close();
       }
    }
}
```

Here is my SQL Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[deleteCustomer]
     @CustID INT
AS
     DELETE FROM [dbo].[Customer]
     WHERE CustID = @CustID
```

Running this code deletes the record as I want, but doesn't output the right label, when I try and delete a record that doesn't exist or exists it gives me the 'Does not exist' text output never the 'Deleted' text output in the IF statement.

What do I need to change in the IF statement in order for it to see that the `command.ExecuteNonQuery` equals anything or not, so I can get it to show the correct output? Thank you.

Comment: Your using statement looks strange, it could mess things up. take a look at :https://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-SE/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: By the way, why are you using `command.ExecuteNonQuery` two times?

Comment: @mmushtaq - to be **absolutely** sure it's deleted :-)

Comment: @mmushtaq - nailed it. No matter whether it existed or not the first time it's called, it definitely won't the second time, and so the code was correctly reflecting that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get `@@ROWCOUNT` as follow:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[deleteCustomer]
@CustID INT
AS
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Customer]
WHERE CustID = @CustID
select @@ROWCOUNT
```

It will return *`No of effective rows`*

Remove this statement

<s>command.ExecuteNonQuery();</s>

and Just use this one

```
 deletedCustomers = command.ExecuteScalar();
```

***EDIT***

```
try
       {
           conn.Open();

           deletedCustomers = command.ExecuteScalar();

           if (deletedCustomers > 0) {
               lblError.Text = "Deleted!";   
           }
           else
           {
               lblError.Text = "Customer ID does not exist";
           }

           conn.Close();              
       }
```

Comment: I added select @@ROWCOUNT to my delete customer procedure.
I'm still getting the wrong output from my IF statement.

Comment: @Minosum - if you want to go down the `@@ROWCOUNT` route, you need to switch to `ExecuteScalar` as well to read the value - but have you tried just reducing the double call to `ExecuteNonQuery` that was pointed out in the comments and keeping the rest of your code the same?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a newbie, not sure where I'm calling it twice?

Comment: @Minosum - look at your code. In whatever editor you're looking at it in, I'm sure there's a `Find` or `Search` function. Try to find `ExecuteNonQuery`. You'll find that you're calling it twice on successive lines (unless the code you've shown us is completely different from your actual code, which there are some indications of already, but in which case, you're just making it hard for us to help you by not showing us the actual code)

Comment: Thanks people, I just deleted the extra executenonQuery, and I added command.executeScalar to equal deletedcustomer int variable, seems to be working thanks for everyones help :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition, if you read carefully [MSDN documentation on ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) you'll find:

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

Stored procedure is not listed. Add `select @@ROWCOUNT` (see @mmushtaq answer) or use `DELETE FROM [dbo].[Customer] WHERE CustID = @CustID` instead of procedure. And finally: do you really need procedure for such queries?

Comment: I've certainly seen examples in the past where it does return row counts if the first statement in a stored procedure is one of the above mentioned statements, despite the documentation appearing not to support that interpretation. The double-call that mmushtaq points out in the comments mean it doesn't matter whether it (would have) worked via the stored procedure.

Comment: It needs to be a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases  `command.ExecuteNonQ‌​uery` is returning -1 as return value

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

as suggested in other posts, You need to get @@ROWCOUNT

refer the link for more details  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx